# Wordpress Custom Post type archive page template not being rendered

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm creating a plugin and adding a custom post type ssd_vehicles. The single page template is working and it's using the template files I set in the filter 'single_template' but the 'archive_template' is not working it goes into the condition of `is_post_type_archive ( 'ssd_vehicles' )` but it doesn't use the template file I return to 'archive_template'

ssd-plugin.php

```
register_post_type('ssd_vehicles',
   array(
            'labels'      => array(
                'name'          => __('SSD Vehicles', 'textdomain'),

                'singular_name' => __('SSD Vehicle', 'textdomain'),
            ),
                'public'      => true,
                'has_archive' => 'ssd_vehicles',
                'rewrite'     => array( 'slug' => 'ssd_vehicle' ),
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields' ),
        )

    );

add_filter('single_template', array('MyClass','create_single_template'));
add_filter('archive_template', array('MyClass','create_archive_template'));

public static function create_single_template( $single_template ){
    
    global $post;   
    if ( 'ssd_vehicles' === $post->post_type ) {
        //THIS WORKS AND DISPLAYS THE CORRECT TEMPLATE FILE

        $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/single-ssd_vehicles.php';
    }
    return $single_template;
}

public static function create_archive_template( $archive_template ){
    global $post;   
    if ( is_post_type_archive ( 'ssd_vehicles' ) ) {

        //CODE GOES HERE BUT THE THIS TEMPLATE FILE IS NOT BEING USED
        $archive_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/archive-ssd_vehicles.php';
    }
   
    return $archive_template;
}
```

Comment: I've rarely seen the use of a string in the 'has_archive' =>  parameter, and then that being rewritten in the next param. Perhaps just try changing that to have a value of 'true'. Like so  'has_archive' => true

Comment: I wanted the archive page to use the plural of the single page template so example.com/ssd_vehicles (archive) and example.com/ssd_vehicle/{vehicle name} for (single)

Comment: @DubVader already tried changing it to true archive page I made is not being rendered but it's rendering something in the template files

Comment: Understood. One other thing you can try is flushing rewrite rules, or re-saving permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't calling for a class require a class ? `array( 'MyClass', 'create_single_template' );`.
It seems to work on my end.

```
add_filter( 'single_template', array( 'MyClass1', 'create_single_template' ) );
class MyClass1 {
    public static function create_single_template( $single_template ){ 
        if ( is_singular( 'ssd_vehicles' ) ) {
            $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/single-ssd_vehicles.php';
        };
        return $single_template;
    }
};

add_filter( 'archive_template', array( 'MyClass2', 'create_archive_template' ) );
class MyClass2 {
    public static function create_archive_template( $archive_template ) { 
        if ( is_post_type_archive ( 'ssd_vehicles' ) ) {
            $archive_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/archive-ssd_vehicles.php';
        };
        return $archive_template;
    }
};
```

Additionally, to [step away from global variable in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89321/190376), `$global $post` to retrieve the `post_type` can be replaced by `get_post_type()` or `is_singular( 'custom_post_type_slug' )`. You could also remove the whole class thing and switch to straight functions to make thing easier (as they don't seems to have a real role right now).

Comment: Sorry I did not mention that there's an existing `MyClass` that houses the single and archive template in the plugin. The problem is these methods are being executed as shown in the code comments but the archive template being used for the archive page for my custom post type is different so for example I have echoed HELLO WORLD on archive-ssd_vehicles.php it doesn't show up I think this only mean one thing that the archive template I made is being overriden by another template

Answer (score 0):

It seems that elementor is overriding my custom archive template. I tried disabling and enabling plugins and it seem to work but when elementor pro is active it overrides the template.